# Font Sizing Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, mobile, font-size

I have designed an iOS app in Photoshop. My canvas is 1242 X 2208 at 401 resolution as I was designing it for the iPhone 6 Plus.

The developer I am working with has asked me to provide a list for the font sizes used within the design. My Navigation Bar font size is 9.34 pt according to Photoshop, however, the HIG says font should not be smaller than 10 pt. Is this because I used such a high resolution?

I guess what I am wondering is should I recreate the design at 72 resolution in order to provide accurate font sizes to the developer?

I have been providing assets @2X and @3X using resonator: http://resonator.cc/ and he has not been complaining about those.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you rephrase your question to be more clear, and some formatting wouldn't kill you know ;)